# ActiveX doesn't work in ExtJs application in Chrome with Neptune plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, embed, activexobject

My web application (localhost:8083/myapp) uses Java on server side and ExtJS 4.1.3 on client side, browser Google Chrome.
By clicking button in my web application I want to open new window with ActiveX object.
I installed Neptune plugin (http://www.meadroid.com/neptune/about.htm), which enables ActiveX in Google Chrome. I can't use Chrome extensions like IETab because they break my markup, and I don't want to load the whole app under IE.
Manual installation of plugin: copy npmeadax.dll to C:\Documents and Settings\User_name\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Plugin Data, register it with regsvr32.exe npmeadax.dll and reopen Google Chrome. *Note*: npmeadax.dll is available after custom installation with installer.
Plugin only needs embed tag to be added to a page with attribute type='application/x-meadco-neptune-ax' and attribute param-location set to location.href.
**The problem is** ActiveX object works when I use plain html pages, but doesn't work when I use the same code within web application. In plain html pages when I debug loadPage function, after tbody.appendChild(embed) information bar appears at the top of the window and says: "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer. Click here for options." I allow blocked content and everything works as expected: word file opens with string 'Hello world!' added. But in web application activeX is not activised.  /myapp//js/app/controller/somepackage/embed.html is the same as C:\embed.html
Here is the code for plain html pages:
C:\button.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="open win" onclick="window.open('embed.html','_blank')" />
</body>
</html>
```

C:\embed.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPage() {
            var lh = location.href;
            var embed = document.createElement('embed');
            embed.setAttribute('width','100%');
            embed.setAttribute('height','100%');
            embed.setAttribute('type','application/x-meadco-neptune-ax');
            embed.setAttribute('param-location',lh);
            var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            tbody.appendChild(embed);                
            try {
                var w = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
                var docText;
                var obj;
                if (w != null)
                {
                    w.Visible = true; //set to false to stop the Word document from opening
                    obj = w.Documents.Open("C:\\A.doc");
                    docText = obj.Content;
                    w.Selection.TypeText("Hello world!");
                    w.Documents.Save();
                }
            }
            catch(e) {}
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadPage()">
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code within web application:
SomeForm.js (ExtJs controller):

```
Ext.define("App.controller.somepackage.SomeForm", {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
...
init: function() {
    this.application.on('click_button', this.onButtonClick, this);
    ...
},      
onButtonClick: function() {
    var win = window.open("/myapp//js/app/controller/somepackage/embed.html","_blank");        
}
...
```

UPDATE:
in plain html page embed tag added in javascript looks like:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-meadco-neptune-ax" param-location="file:///C:/embed.html">
```

in web-application embed tag looks like:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-meadco-neptune-ax" param-location="http://localhost:8083/myapp//js/app/controller/somepackage/embed.html">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Neptune uses settings of current version of IE, which is installed in operating system. I use IE8, so I configured safety settings and everything worked fine - I got a dialog window asking about safety of ActiveX component. I have a localized version of IE, so I am sorry if I named something wrong.  Here are the actions in IE:
1. Choose Service -> Explorer settings -> tab "Safety".
2. Choose "Local intranet". Click Nodes, then click Additional.  Add

```
http://localhost
```

click Add, Close, then ОК.
3. Choose Another...
4. For "ActiveX elements and connection modules":
Automatic requests of ActiveX management elements - on
Run ActiveX elements' scripts marked as safe - on
Loading of unsigned ActiveX elements - suggest
Loading of signed ActiveX elements - suggest
Run ActiveX elements and connection modules - on
Usage of ActiveX elements not marked as safe for use - suggest
Action of binary code and scripts - on
Allow to use ActiveX without request only to asserted domains - off
Allow to run ActiveX management elements that was not used previously without warning - on
Allow scripts - on

After that I reopened Google Chrome.